# CartoDBfy'ed Table not appearing in editor on local environment?

Tags: carto

I'm trying to create data tables by SQL and visualize them by CARTO editor.

But between my local and CARTO environments, the results of CartoDBfy were different : local was failed and CARTO was success.

What is the different between each environments?
And what should I do to deal with the table in CARTO editor?

Details are bellow.

**1. Local Environment**

I built the development CartoDB environment on cloud server, according to 'http://cartodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html'. 
The installation was finished successfully and I can use CARTO without problems.

Then I created and CartoDBfy'ed a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    cartodb_id INTEGER,
    the_geom geometry(Geometry,4326),
    the_geom_webmercator geometry(Geometry,3857),
    code character(4) NOT NULL
);

SELECT cdb_cartodbfytable('test');
```

These queries were finished successfully. The returned message was bellow.

> {"rows":[{"cdb_cartodbfytable":"test"}],"time":0.068,"fields":{"cdb_cartodbfytable":{"type":"regclass"}},"total_rows":1,"notices":["trigger
>   \"track_updates\" for table \"test\" does not exist,
>   skipping","trigger \"update_the_geom_webmercator_trigger\" for table
>   \"test\" does not exist, skipping","trigger \"test_quota\" for table
>   \"test\" does not exist, skipping","trigger \"test_quota_per_row\" for
>   table \"test\" does not exist, skipping"]}

But the table **NEVER appeared** on the Datasets dashboard.

**2. CARTO Environment**

I executed same queries in my CARTO Account(xxx.caro.com) via SQL API, they were finishing successfully with the same message and **APPEARED** in the dashboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you CartoDBfy a table you adapt it to CARTO, but it does not register it in the metadata that the Editor/Builder use to retrieve the list of datasets. This behaviour is what we call "Ghost Tables"

When you go into your Dashboard in CARTO, a Ghost Tables Manager script checks the consistency between the metadata (the user_table and visualization models) and the data in your user database. It registers everything that looks like a proper Carto table and it's not registered already as a User Table.

In order to force this behaviour in your environment, you can go into the Rails console and force the GhostTablesManager to run:

```
bundle exec rails c development
u = User.find(username:'your_username')
Carto::GhostTablesManager.new(u.id).link_ghost_tables_synchronously
```

Now, the next time you go into your dashboard you should see your new table.

And, if you're interested, here you can find the GhostTablesManager code: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/3d462fe0569af595760f02740270763ba3b76205/lib/carto/ghost_tables_manager.rb

Comment: I am able to see new table after running the code! Thanks a lot!